# TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType (Python3, kivy)

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, types, kivy

I'm just learning to code and I'm discovering kivy.

I've decided to write all the interface in a kivy file and I'm drawing the interface with canvas. That's why I want to work with coordinates, that depend on coordinates of the center of the window, for example.

```
#:import win kivy.core.window
#:import Line kivy.graphics.Line

<Frontend>:
    rect_dim: 900
    cent: win.Window._get_center()
    c_ox: (self.cent[0] - self.rect_dim)/2
    c_oy: self.cent[1] - self.rect_dim/2
    pos_x: (self.cent[0] - self.rect_dim)/2
    pos_y: self.cent[1]-self.rect_dim/2
    pts_vrt: [self.c_ox + self.rect_dim/3, self.c_oy, self.c_ox + self.rect_dim/3, self.c_oy+900, self.c_ox + 2/3*self.rect_dim, self.c_oy, self.c_ox + 2/3*self.rect_dim, self.c_oy+900]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 0,0,1,1
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.rect_dim, self.rect_dim
            pos: self.pos_x, self.pos_y
            radius: [(40, 40), (40, 40), (40, 40), (40, 40)]
    on_parent:
        for i in range(0, len(root.pts_vrt), 4): self.canvas.add(Line(points=root.pts_vrt[i:i+4]))
```

When I run thit code I get: " TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType" for `pos: self.pos_x, self.pos_y`, that seems to me a little bit confusing, as if pos_x and pos_y are of the same type, that is float, I've checked in a python file.
At the same time if I create Rectagle in the same manner that I trace these lines, it works fine, though, I'm not able to diversify colors. And I want to see my lines on my rectangle.

```
#:import win kivy.core.window
#:import Line kivy.graphics.Line
#:import RRectangle kivy.graphics.RoundedRectangle

<Frontend>:
    rect_dim: 900
    cent: win.Window._get_center()
    c_ox: (self.cent[0] - self.rect_dim)/2
    c_oy: self.cent[1] - self.rect_dim/2
    pos_x: (self.cent[0] - self.rect_dim)/2
    pos_y: self.cent[1]-self.rect_dim/2
    pts_vrt: [self.c_ox + self.rect_dim/3, self.c_oy, self.c_ox + self.rect_dim/3, self.c_oy+900, self.c_ox + 2/3*self.rect_dim, self.c_oy, self.c_ox + 2/3*self.rect_dim, self.c_oy+900]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 0,1,1,1
    on_parent:
        self.canvas.add(RRectangle(size=(self.rect_dim, self.rect_dim), pos=((self.cent[0] - self.rect_dim)/2, self.cent[1]-self.rect_dim/2), radius=[(40, 40), (40, 40), (40, 40), (40, 40)]))
        for i in range(0, len(root.pts_vrt), 4): self.canvas.add(Line(points=root.pts_vrt[i:i+4]))
```

So I don't really understang, what python doesn't like in the first case and if it is impossible to counter, how can I draw figures of different colors in the second case?

Answer (score 0):

Good day. I think your problem is the pos_x, pos_y variables. The only place I see them defined is under your `Frontend` widget. To access it from that widget, use the keyword `root`. i.e. `size: root.pos_x, root.pos_y`.

Comment: Good day. Thank you for your answer! I’ve already tried to replace ```pos: self.pos_x, self.pos_y``` by ```pos: root.pos_x, root.pos_y```, but I get the same error in the end.

Comment: The same: "TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType"